# Optimal Apple Eating Strategy

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

You hate apples. As a result, you have angered the apple king and are being punished. You will have to eat $n$ apples before the apple king is willing to let you leave. The apples are marked from $1$ to $n$ and you have to eat them sequentially starting with $1$ and ending with $n$.

For every apple you eat, you do not know how long it is going to take you to eat it or how much weight it is going to add to your stomach until you have actually eaten the apple. Let $a_i$ denote how long it takes you to eat apple $i$ and $b_i$ denote how much weight apple $i$ is going to add to your stomach. You learn the true value of $a_i$ and $b_i$ as soon as you finish eating apple $i$. Once you start eating an apple, you have to finish it before you can do anything else. $a_i$s are i.i.d. with CDF $F$ while $b_i$s are i.i.d. with CDF $G$. $F$ and $G$ are known to you.

Apple king is a merciful king, each time after you finish eating an apple, he allows you a chance to have a digestion break. You can rest for as long as you want. If you choose not to rest, you can move directly onto the next apple. Let $r_i$ denote the duration of your rest after finish eating apple $i$. The more apples you have in your stomach, the worse you feel. For every apple you eat without taking a digestion break, you will feel pain at a faster rate. For example, if you choose to eat apple $2$ right after apple $1$, the pain for apple $1$ is $b_1$ while the pain for apple $2$ is $b_1+b_2$. If you choose to rest for $r_1$ before eating apple $2$, the pain for apple $2$ is $b_1+b_2-r_1$. So the pain for eating apple $k$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} r_i$. Pain is non-negative, so the maximum $r_i$ you can pick every time resets pain to zero.

Your objective is to get out as fast as you can with minimum discomfort. That is you are trying to minimize $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_i)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} r_i)$ by choosing each $r_i$.

What is your optimal strategy here and why?

There is also an extension of the problem where the objective function becomes $\alpha(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_i)+\beta\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} r_i)$. $α$ and $β$ are known and both greater than $0$.

Comment: But I love apples. Downvoted! Just kidding. But you likely should add some ideas of your own  to the post via an [edit].

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried, your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include an important condition in the problem: $a_i$s are i.i.d. with CDF $F$ while $b_i$s are i.i.d. with CDF $G$. $F$ and $G$ are known to you. This problem is presented to my by a friend who studies industrial engineering. Well to start, the second term that measures discomfort can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n (n-i+1)b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)r_i$. And the objective function can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i+\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i+1)b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (1+i-n)r_i$.

Comment: Since pain accumulates at increasing speed, in my opinion, the optimal strategy is to pick each $r_i=b_i$ so that the pain for the next apple is determined only by $b_{i+1}$.

Comment: I'm stuck on a formal proof for this strategy. Furthermore, this problem has an extension where the objective is to minimize $\alpha(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_i)+\beta\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sum_{i=1}^{k} b_i-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} r_i)$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known and both greater than $0$. I don't think my intuition would hold.

Comment: Can the pain be negative if you rest long enough? And why are you introducing the $a_i$ (and also $b_i$ if the answer to the previous question is affirmative)? As far as I can tell they don't enter into the optimisation.

Comment: Pain is non-negative, so the maximum $r_i$ you can pick every time resets pain to zero. You are right, $a_i$s do not really matter in the optimization. They are included there because they account towards how long you have to stay there eating apples. But one can easily reduce the problem to just the $b_i$s and $r_i$s.